# Load JSON file without AJAX or HTTP get

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently struggling to read a data file in my project. The easy way would be to just make a HTTP get request to the resource and continue the parse the data.

However, the application I'm writing is going to be used in a iOS webview, and then I can't use any AJAX-calls. Basically, it's a local `index.html`.

Structure:

```
index.html
-- data
   |-- data.json
```

I can't really "include" the json file in the project because this file will change before the app boots.

**What I've tried so far**

Converting the `data.json` to a javascript file:

```
var data = {"object": bar}
```

And then add a script tag to the `index.html` file including it. This won't work because the `data.json`can't be modified by my app.

I think this might be a fairly common problem, but I still haven't found a solution for it. All HTTP-get solutions are out the window it seems.

Comment: Question is not clear. Where in index.html you want to load the json.
Do you want to load that into dom or what ?

Comment: "This won't work because the data.json can't be modified by my app.": why not?

Comment: If you want to access the local filesystem, see the duplicate. If you want something like "persistent local storage" for a website, see "HTML5 localStorage".

Comment: @Andy because there is now server side. Using the client to edit file data isn't an option I guess?